# Thread status TimedWait. How to debug?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My application run some complex threads that fetch maps in a background thread and draw them. Sometimes if I run the app for a couple hours on a slow network I seem to be getting it into a weird state where all my threads status are showing TimedWait or Wait (except the ones that are Native such as main).

What is the cause of this? How can I debug it? I am absolutely lost and I know this is a bit of a general question but I would appreciate it if someone could  point me to the right direction. EG:

1. How to pin point the cause of the problem.
2. What king of issues generally cause all the threads to lock up?
3. Anybody seen anything similar?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It's right there in the stack trace at the bottom.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey that's just one thread iv'e highlighted. Al those threads above it are in TimeWait as well. I don't know what has caused this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timed wait is simply a thread which is blocked on some O/S level call which has a timeout specified, such as a simple wait primitive (`Object.wait()`) or a socket operation (`Socket read()/write()`), a thread queue etc.  It's quite normal for any complex program to have several or many of these - I have an application server which routinely has hundreds, even thousands.

Your threads may be backing up on non-responsive connections and may not be misbehaving at all, per se.  It may simply be that you need to program them to detect and abort an idle connection.

Click on each of the threads which you are concerned about and analyze their stack trace for how they got there.

Most decent profiling tools (and application containers) will have the option of printing a full stack trace, and more modern ones will do a dead-lock and live-lock analysis for you.  The JVisualVM tool distributed with Sun's JDK and available on the net as VisualVM will do this and it's very effective. Most decent profilers will also show lock acquisition in the stack trace (yours, above, is not in that view).

Otherwise, you are looking for two or more threads contending for the same lock or acquiring the same locks in a different order.  You may need to do this manually by actually examining the source and annotating your stack trace, but you should be able to whittle down likely candidates if your tool doesn't point right to the conflicting threads.